# How to merge audio into video using MediaMuxer

Tags: android, android-studio, mediamuxer

I want to merge audio into video using MediaMuxer, but each time when i strat the app, it crashed. I researched alot but code is correct(in my prospective). 
It counts frame in logcat but after it stopes. it doesn't even show Toast which i was provided in code to know.  Or is there any way to merge audio into video.

here's my code :

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "final2.mp4");
    file.createNewFile();
    output = file.getAbsolutePath();

    MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    videoExtractor.setDataSource(videopath);;

    MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    audioExtractor.setDataSource(audiopath);

    Log.d(TAG, "Video Extractor Track Count " + videoExtractor.getTrackCount() );
    Log.d(TAG, "Audio Extractor Track Count " + audioExtractor.getTrackCount() );

    MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(output, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

    videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
    MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
    int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

    audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
    MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
    int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);

    Log.d(TAG, "Video Format " + videoFormat.toString() );
    Log.d(TAG, "Audio Format " + audioFormat.toString() );

    boolean sawEOS = false;
    int frameCount = 0;
    int offset = 100;
    int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
    ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
    ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


    videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
    audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

    muxer.start();

    while (!sawEOS)
    {
        videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
        videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


        if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
            sawEOS = true;
            videoBufferInfo.size = 0;

        }
        else
        {
            videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
            videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME;
            muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
            videoExtractor.advance();


            frameCount++;
            Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
            Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "frame:" + frameCount , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    boolean sawEOS2 = false;
    int frameCount2 =0;
    while (!sawEOS2)
    {
        frameCount2++;

        audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;
        audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

        if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
            sawEOS2 = true;
            audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
            audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.getSampleFlags();
            muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
            audioExtractor.advance();


            Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
            Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "frame:" + frameCount2 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    muxer.stop();
    muxer.release();
```

Here's my logcat :

```
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3552)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3633)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:164)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1491)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
09-03 13:31:56.350 31898 31898 E   ActivityThread                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
09-03 13:40:05.646 2792 2792 E     WVMExtractor com.mycompany.myapp             Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
```

Comment: Can you the post the crash log

Comment: @SahilManchanda I edited in my question post.

Comment: Try to execute your code in background i.e. use Async class

Comment: @SahilManchanda it didnt work. same issue

Comment: can you post the new cod that you tried with AsyncTask

Comment: @SahilManchanda i have posted in answer section

Comment: Please give the audio and video link so that i give it a try on my end

Comment: @SahilManchanda there's no link i get them from device storage

Comment: I understand but i need to have access to those media, can you email it to me, my email id is sahil.manchanda2@gmail.com

Comment: @SahilManchanda you can pit any media file from you device

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Merge extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        Log.i("result", result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] p1)
    {
        String au = p1[0];
        String vi = p1[1];

        Log.i("au", au);
        Log.i("vi", vi);

        //Log.d(TAG, "Video Extractor Track Count " + videoExtractor.getTrackCount() );
        //Log.d(TAG, "Audio Extractor Track Count " + audioExtractor.getTrackCount() );

        try
        {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "m24.mp4");
            file.createNewFile();

            output = file.getAbsolutePath();

            MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            videoExtractor.setDataSource(vi);

            MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
            audioExtractor.setDataSource(au);

            MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(output, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

            videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
            MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
            int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

            audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
            MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
            int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);

            Log.d(TAG, "Video Format " + videoFormat.toString() );
            Log.d(TAG, "Audio Format " + audioFormat.toString() );

            boolean sawEOS = false;
            int frameCount = 0;
            int offset = 100;
            int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
            ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
            ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


            videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
            audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

            muxer.start();

            while (!sawEOS)
            {
                videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
                videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);


                if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
                {
                    Log.d("GGv", "saw input EOS.");
                    sawEOS = true;
                    videoBufferInfo.size = 0;

                }
                else
                {
                    videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
                    videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME;
                    muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
                    videoExtractor.advance();


                    frameCount++;
                    //Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                    //Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

                }
            }

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "frame:" + frameCount , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            boolean sawEOS2 = false;
            int frameCount2 =0;
            while (!sawEOS2)
            {
                frameCount2++;

                audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;
                audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

                if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0)
                {
                    Log.d("GGa", "saw input EOS.");
                    sawEOS2 = true;
                    audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
                    audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.getSampleFlags();
                    muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
                    audioExtractor.advance();


                    //Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                    //Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

                }
            }

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "frame:" + frameCount2 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            muxer.stop();
            muxer.release();

            String su = "Su";

            return su;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {}
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
Merge m = new Merge();
                m.execute(audiopath, videopath);
```